# Pseudoinverse and SVD

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, pseudoinverse

For the SVD $$\textbf{A=U}\boldsymbol\Sigma \textbf{V}^{*}$$

Where $\textbf{U}$ and $\textbf{V}$ are unitary

By partitioning the matrix $\textbf{A}$, we have the following:
$$\textbf{A} = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}
                \textbf{U}_{1} &\textbf{U}_{2} 
            \end{array}
            \right]
            \left[
            \begin{array}{c|c}
            \tilde{\boldsymbol\Sigma} & \textbf{0} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{0} & \textbf{0}
            \end{array}
            \right]
            \begin{bmatrix}
            \textbf{V}_{1}^{\ast} \\
            \textbf{V}_{2}^{\ast}
\end{bmatrix}$$

\begin{equation*}
    \textbf{A} = 
    \textbf{U}_{1} \tilde{\boldsymbol\Sigma} \textbf{V}_{1}^{\ast}.
\end{equation*}

Where $\tilde{\boldsymbol\Sigma}=diag(\sigma_1,..,\sigma_k)$

Prove that $$\textbf{A}^\dagger=\textbf{V}\boldsymbol\Sigma^\dagger \textbf{U}^*$$
is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $\textbf{A}$

Where $$\boldsymbol\Sigma^{\dagger} = diag(\sigma_{1}^{-1},\sigma_{2}^{-1},..,\sigma_{k}^{-1},0,..,0)$$

After some simple calculations we have that $\textbf{AA}^\dagger\textbf{=U}_{1}\textbf{U}_{1}^{*}$ which shows that it is conjugate symmetric.
However, when I want to prove that $\textbf{AA}^{\dagger}\textbf{A=A}$, I will have $\textbf{AA}^{\dagger}\textbf{A=U}_1\textbf{U}_1^{*}\textbf{A}$ but is $\textbf{U}_1\textbf{U}_1^{*}=\begin{bmatrix}
                \textbf{I}_{k} &\textbf{0} \\
                   \textbf{0} & \textbf{0}
            \end{bmatrix}$? And why?

Comment: I am so sorry for any confusion. I have now edited the text and I hope it's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can easily say things about $U_1U_1^*$. But you can calculate
$$
A^* A=V_1\tilde\Sigma^* U_1^*U_1\tilde\Sigma V_1^*.
$$
Since $U$ is a unitary, its columns are orthonormal. If we denote the columnss by $u_1,\ldots,u_k$, then the entries of $U_1^*U_1$ are $u_k^*u_j=\delta_{k,j}$, so $U_1^*U_1=I_kV_1^*V_1$. Then
$$
A^*A=V_1V_1^*,
$$
and
$$
AA^*A=AV_1V_1^*=U_1\tilde\Sigma V_1^*V_1V_1^*=U_1\tilde\Sigma V_1^*=A.
$$

Comment: Please consider upvoting if you found this (and other(s)) answer useful.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. I can know understand the logic behind it. The only edit that I can suggest is that instead of using the rows, just because of the way that I partitioned the matrix, we have to use the fact that the columns are orthonormal.

Comment: Indeed, edited.